# How to set SwiftUI preview canvas background?

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a UI component which has a whitish back and is hard to see from the SwiftUI preview canvas.

Is there a way I can set the background of the preview canvas so I can see the render UI component with a light color background?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to achieve it with a workaround by using a `ZStack` with a `Rectangle` view.

```
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            SampleUI()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You actually don't need the rectangle with a ZStack:

```
static var previews: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.black)
        SampleUI()
    }
}
```

If you're previewing on an iPhone X or above, here's how you make the color display over the safe area:

```
static var previews: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.black).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        SampleUI()
    }
}
```